# Controlling Major Compaction in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am relatively new to Cassandra, so I apologize in advance if I am missing something obvious.
So, I am using cassandra 1.0.12 in a one node cluster and doing heavy writes and deletes (about 1000/sec). Writes are more frequent then deletes as a result my disk space goes on increasing. If I understand correctly the compaction would help me achieve that (Major and Minor). So I changed setGc_grace_seconds to 0 and setMin_compaction_threshold to 2. Even after setting these values I am seeing SSTable count 4 for that Column Family, shouldn't it kick compaction when the SSTable count is 2 ? Also, when does major compaction kick in and how can I control it (I want to run it more often).

Comment: Be careful about setting gc_grace_seconds to 0 if you're doing deletes at less than ConsistencyLevel.ALL; you can easily end up with zombie data: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DistributedDeletes

Comment: I think it should be alright as I am using a one node cluster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Size-tiered compaction, minor compaction is triggered automatically sometimes after at least min_compaction_threshold SSTables of **similiar size** has been created on disk. So in your case, sometimes after two similiar sized SSTables have been created, minor compaction will kick in and merge those two SSTables to a new SSTable.
[Tuning options for Size-tiered compaction](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/tuning)

Major compaction is manually triggered through [nodetool](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/nodetool). *"For each column family in keyspace, this compacts all existing SSTables into a single SSTable".*

Comment: I think I had overlooked **similar size** thanks for pointing it out, perhaps this was the reason why we were not seeing compaction kick in.